# javascript display attributes from each object (act as foreach)

Tags: javascript, php

I've returned a result from a method (it's collected multiple objects), and I'm trying to display each object's properties (well certain ones)... but it's only displaying **the last** object in the notification-list.

Below is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
        // Add loading state
        $('.menu').html('Loading notifications ...');
        // Set request
        var id = "{{ Auth::user()->id }}";
        var request = $.get('/notifications/' + id);

        // When it's done
        request.done(function(response) {

            console.log(response);
            for(var index in response) {
               if (response.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                   var attr = response[index];
                   $('.notification-list').html(attr.action + ' By: ' + attr.added_by + ' : ' + attr.created_at)
                 }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: IF any of you read you would have a response like z4f1 i clearly state: **its only displaying the last object in the notification-list** it's why i'm always reluctant to post on here because of the snobby community lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are putting in the new values everytime. Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
        // Add loading state
        $('.menu').html('Loading notifications ...');
        // Set request
        var id = "{{ Auth::user()->id }}";
        var request = $.get('/notifications/' + id);

        // When it's done
        request.done(function(response) {

            console.log(response);
            for(var index in response) {
               if (response.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
                   var attr = response[index];
                   $('.notification-list').append(attr.action + ' By: ' + attr.added_by + ' : ' + attr.created_at)
                 }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks that solved my issue@Z4F1 glad you managed to see the problem unlike the others :p

Comment: No problem. I love to help!